# Soundcloud API: Is it possible to get the 'playlist/set' data of my Favorites?

Tags: api, playlist, soundcloud, favorites

I'm build an app where I have already been successful in create and displaying a 'set'/playlist of tracks uploaded to an account, however I would like to be able to get the similar data for the lists of tracks by OTHER users which I have added to my Favorites.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the **Subresources** section in the docs: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/users

If you know the user id, you can get their tracks/playlists using the following.

```
/users/{id}/tracks

/users/{id}/playlists

/users/{id}/favorites
```

Comment: Hi, I know how to get the tracks and playlists uploaded 'by' a specific user, but what I'm after is the 'Favorites' list, which can contain tracks uploaded by 'other' users.  thx.

I suppose I'm hoping that the 'Favorites' is actually, simply a 'playlist' with an id I can use in my app.

Comment: ahah! Just spotted it now, within the /users section. Many thanks!